# Remesh question

Tags: remesh

I wonder how can one sculpt a character that has his arms cross and then remesh it and not have the arms merge with the body. If there is a technique or this is not just possible.

Comment: The arms would need to be in a different object

Comment: Yes, this is essentially the purpose of the remesh modifier/ function.

Comment: I think a lot of the time you'd model the character in a default position and then pose them afterwards

Comment: Thx alot for the answers 